# LightBox with link support

Tags: hyperlink, lightbox

I need Light box with link support.. Like for example when I open http://www.example.com/index.php#lightbox1, a light box should appear over index.php and it should contain contents of lightbox1.php.

Is there any plugin or pre made script?

Answer (score 0):

Use below link and you will get solution for your requirement.

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but I asked for another here I explain..
When I got to http://www.example.com/index.php#page

then it show contents of page.php in a lightbox..
Thanks!